# How to use a Icon as a button to submit img to php and sql

Tags: php, html

i don't have 
    any idea how to make a icon  as a input tag i expect the output to be
    the icon will use as a input tag for my codes

Thank you in Advance

```
<form action="includes/upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form data">
       <i class='fas fa-camera bg-primary btn-circle btn-md'></i>
     </form>
```

Comment: i want user to upload img by clicking on the icon as a input tag to 
    upload IMG to my website.

Comment: This would be a job for JavaScript, attaching an event handler to the icon. Alternatively, you could use a `<form>` POST, and make use of an `<input type="submit">` with a background image of the icon.

Comment: yo bro thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this,your input file will be as an image

```
.image-upload > input
{
  display: none;
}

.image-upload img
{
  width: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```
<form action="#">
<div class="image-upload">
    <label for="file-input">
        <img src="https://docs.mapbox.com/studio-manual/img/manual/uploads.svg"/>
    </label>

    <input id="file-input" type="file" onchange="this.form.submit();e.preventDefault();"/>
    <input type="submit">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: bro. there is a other problem. where do i put the submit btn. i mean the (type="submit" name="submit")

Comment: Did you mean when choose the file the form submitted and upload directly?

Comment: what do you want exactly?

Comment: what should i put in the $_POST method? usually it is the submit btn. but the thing is i want the submit btn to be the img.

Comment: yes just like that. it submitted and upload directly

Comment: This what you need,okay?

Comment: what should i do?

Comment: Do for what :) ?!

Comment: what should i call in the php script? isset$_POST then what?

Comment: see this will help you https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try to This :

```
<button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a button for i class icon. Onclick of that icon call a function to upload image. Hide the file input inside a div and then on click of the button, write script to click the input file.

```
 <div style="height:0px;overflow:hidden">
 <input type="file" id="fileInput" name="fileInput" />
 </div>
 <button type="button" onclick="chooseFile();">
 <i class='fas fa-camera bg-primary btn-circle btn-md'></i>
 </button>

<script>
 function chooseFile() {
  $("#fileInput").click();
  }
</script>
```

Don't forget to include the script and css libraries as well.

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Refer to this link : [upload-image-onclick-i class](https://js.do/code/334374)